# Unwrapping Value after parsing JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, string, swift

I currently stuck at get my JSON Parse into a string, here is my Code

```
var SummName = "xxxxx"
        var APIKEY = "xxxx-xxx-43d5-8647-xxxx"



        let urlPath0 = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+SummName+"?api_key="+APIKEY
        let url0 = NSURL(string: urlPath0)
        let session0 = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task0 = session0.dataTaskWithURL(url0!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println(error)
            } else {
                let summonorID_JSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
                var SummonerID = summonorID_JSON["smirknaitia"] as NSDictionary

                let SummID = SummonerID["id"]! as NSString
                println(SummID)
                let urlPath1 = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+SummID+"?api_key="+APIKEY


            }
        })

        task0.resume()
```

It always fails by unwrapping the Value of SummonerID["ID"] into a string

Comment: The API you're referring to is returning "id" as a `long`, not a string. In the future, post either the JSON you are receiving or a link to the API docs for the API you are querying.

Comment: Post the exact error please

Comment: Look into if let  statements for unwrapping optionals

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways `let SummID = SummonerID["id"]! as NSString` can fail:

1. `SummonerID` dictionary doesn't have a value for key "id", so it fails when you try to force-unwrap
2. `SummonerID["id"]!` is not of type `NSString` (or type that can convert to it, like `String`) so it fails when you try to force conversion.

We can't really tell which one it is exactly without seeing the input you have or exact error messages.

A side note: it's not in Swift style to start variable names with uppercase characters. It's best to use camelCase for variables, functions and methods; use UpperCamelCase for classes, structs, enums and enum cases.

Comment: just a quick note, as of Swift 2, the format would be:

`let SummID = SummonerID["id"]! as! NSString`